# Nested cross-validation in grid search for precomputed kernels in scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a precomputed kernel of size NxN. I am using GridSearchCV to tune C parameter of SVM with kernel='precomputed' as follows:

```
C_range = 10. ** np.arange(-2, 9)
param_grid = dict(C=C_range)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(kernel='precomputed'), param_grid=param_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(y=data_label, n_folds=10))
grid.fit(kernel, data_label)
print grid.best_score_
```

This works pretty fine, however since I use the full data for prediction (with grid.predict(kernel)), it overfits (I get precision/recall = 1.0 most of the times).

So I would like to first split my data to 10 chunks (9 for training, 1 for testing) with cross-validation, and in each fold, I want to run GridSearch to tune the C value on the training set, and test on the testing set.

In order to do this, I sliced the kernel matrix into 100x100 and 50x50 submatrices where I run grid.fit() on one of them and grid.predict() on the other.

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 50 should be equal to 100, the number of features at training time
```

I guess training kernel should have the same dimension as testing kernel, but I don't understand why, because I simply compute np.dot(X, X.T) for 100x100, and for 50x50, hence the final kernel have different dimensions..

Answer (score 1):

The scikit learn [doc](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#using-the-gram-matrix) says:

> Set kernel='precomputed' and pass the Gram matrix instead of X in the fit method. At the moment, the kernel values between all training vectors and the test vectors must be provided.

So I guess that it's not possible to do (simple) cross-validation with precomputed kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Custom grid search is fairly straightforward to hack together, though to the best of my knowledge six years later there's still no built-in way of doing it in sklearn. Here's a simple snippet that worked for me to tune the `C` parameter:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.svm import SVC

def precomputed_kernel_GridSearchCV(K, y, Cs, n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=42):
    """A version of grid search CV, 
    but adapted for SVM with a precomputed kernel
    K (np.ndarray) : precomputed kernel
    y (np.array) : labels
    Cs (iterable) : list of values of C to try
    return: optimal value of C
    """
    from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
 
    n = K.shape[0]
    assert len(K.shape) == 2
    assert K.shape[1] == n
    assert len(y) == n
    
    best_score = float('-inf')
    best_C = None
 
    indices = np.arange(n)
    
    for C in Cs:
        # for each value of parameter, do K-fold
        # The performance measure reported by k-fold cross-validation 
        # is the average of the values computed in the loop
        scores = []
        ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=n_splits, test_size=test_size, random_state=random_state)
        for train_index, test_index in ss.split(indices):
            K_train = K[np.ix_(train_index,train_index)]
            K_test = K[np.ix_(test_index, train_index)]
            y_train = y[train_index]
            y_test = y[test_index]
            svc = SVC(kernel='precomputed', C=C)
            svc.fit(K_train, y_train)
            scores.append(svc.score(K_test, y_test))
        if np.mean(scores) > best_score:
            best_score = np.mean(scores)
            best_C = C
    return best_C
```